# jQuery: using css selector to compare position values?

Tags: jquery

Can I use the following code to compare the value of the attribute "left" ?

```
if ($('.pager').css('left') < 100 + 'px')
```

Or should I different code ? (My issue is how to deal with 'px', if I should remove it or at least use it consistently in the code.

thanks

Comment: Can you include a sample of the full context? I think that would make it easier :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `parseInt`, it will ignore the `px` for you:

```
if (parseInt($('.pager').css('left')) < 100)
```

Or you can use the `left` property within [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/):

```
var left = $('.pager').position().left;
if (left < 100) // Etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a variable.

```
var pagerPos = parseInt($('.pager').css('left'))
if (pagerPos < 100) {...}
```

Remember that your if statement is in this case trying to compare a number value to a number value.  You need to use parseInt() to strip off the 'px' held in the CSS.  After that you should be golden!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.style` of the DOM element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)

```
document.getElementById("id").style.left
```